# No audio after USB>HDMI adapter

Tags: sound, usb

Hi I got an Wavlink USB 3.0 to HDMI 2k Adapter to connect two monitors on my laptop, it has its only sound output and now my wireless headset does not work, speakers does not work, is there any how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set which sound device to use in the system settings:

[image: Settings - Sounds]

Double-check the Output Device is set to something other than the Wavlink device, and you should be good to go.